# multiprocessing in a dead loop

Tags: python, multiprocessing, keyboard

I want a function to run in parallel to other processes in the background such that when I click ctrl+a, letter is set to a. However, I tried using multiprocessing which doesn't move on from the function, and also it produces a dead loop when I click ctrl+b a single time.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import keyboard as kb
def AOrB():
    while True:
        if kb.is_pressed("ctrl+a"):
            letter = "a"
            print(letter)
        if kb.is_pressed("ctrl+b"):
            letter = "b"
            print(letter)

def main():
# Other codes
    p = Process(target=AOrB())
    p.start()
    p.join()

    # Other codes

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Clicking ctrl+b once now produces :

```
b
b
b
b
b
b
b
b
```

Comment: Have you protected the `main()` call with `if __name__ == '__main__':`?

Comment: Do you want to achieve that the key pressed would be outputted only once when pressing on it, or is your output ok?

Comment: Yes, I want to achieve that the key pressed would be outputted only once @mbostic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you call the function when you assign it as the target in `Process`. This causes your program to hang at `Process(target=AOrB())`

Try this instead:

```
p = Process(target=AOrB)
```

**EDIT:**

Here is the full code, to output the key only once:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import keyboard as kb
letter = ""
def AOrB():
    global letter
    while True:
        if kb.is_pressed("ctrl+a"):
            if letter != "a":
                letter = "a"
                print(letter)
        if kb.is_pressed("ctrl+b"):
            if letter != "b":
                letter = "b"
                print(letter)

def main():
# Other codes
    p = Process(target=AOrB)
    p.start()
    p.join()

    # Other codes

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: No luck, still in omitting looped sequence of b and a. but it did made me realize that the fact I call the function when you assign it as the target which can be a huge problem later. Thank you

Comment: @Matt Does it work now as you expected after I edited the answer?

Comment: You wouldn't even have to define the variable as global if you don't need it outside of the AOrB() function

Comment: I do need it as global because it will be used by other functions but thanks for the advice

Comment: @Matt Ok, but be careful. Using the variable in different threads can lead to data race, so you should use threading.Lock(). Google about it.

Comment: Thank you for the advice @mbostic